# Drupal: How do I invoke a template in a module?

Tags: templates, drupal-6

I've got some **non-node** data in a custom module of mine and I would like to invoke a template to display the data. This template may get reused for email output, and I would like to basically just bootstrap Drupal and use the template as needed.

I thought I could just do something like:

```
$html = theme('verysmallsnippet', $my_fancy_data_structure);
```

...then create a `verysmallsnippet.tpl.php` file in active theme folder and then expect Drupal to find the template file and evaluate the template with the arguments passed to the theme function. Is this a vast over-simplistic interpretation of how the template engine works -- or do I need to setup the theme registry first? Or What?

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266373/drupal-6-how-to-get-data-from-a-custom-module-in-to-a-template-file), as well as the [theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) documentation, and I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, slightly over-simplistic ;)

For a better introduction than the API doc you linked, start with the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme), and for your specific need, check [Using the theme layer (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/165706).

In order for your example to work you need to tell the theme registry about your template by implementing [hook_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6):

```
function yourModule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $items = array();
  $items['verysmallsnippet'] = array(
    'arguments' => array('my_fancy_data_structure' => array()), // Change array() to a fitting default
    'template' => 'verysmallsnippet',
  );

  return $items;
}
```

You can define more details in that hook, but this is the minimum you need in order to get a template file used (the engine will add the 'tpl.php' part for your when looking for the file).

**NOTE:** You need to trigger a rebuild of the theme registry every time you add or change a hook_theme() implementation, otherwise your changes will not take effect.

Comment: Oh, actually this puts a lot of the pieces together in my head, in particular, how does the template file "know how to name variables" in the template. I will investigate the theming guide. I had seen something that was more clear than the two things I has listed but was unable to locate it again whilst searching. Thank you very much!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but to "tell the theme registry about my hook_theme implementation change" I should clear the cache by either the admin menu or using the drupal_rebuild_theme_registry() call -- right?

Comment: @altCognito: Glad to have helped. As for the "know how to name variables" in the template part, you might want to take a special look at the concept of `template_preprocess()` functions in the docs - the basic idea of those is that you pass a bare minimum of needed data to your initial theme() invocation, and the preprocess function takes care of 'expanding' that into all the different variables needed in the template (in other words, keep the coding logic out of the template and put it in the preprocess function, like e.g. creating proper links from paths, calculating pager information, etc.)

Comment: @altCognito: Sorry, did not notice your second comment in time. Yup, clearing the cache via admin menu is the easiest way during development (`drupal_rebuild_theme_registry()` would be the way to do this from code, which is what admin menu uses when you clear the caches).